# How to serve service-worker.js from spring boot properly?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-boot, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

The browser complains the file is behind a redirect:

```
DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: 
The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.
```

What i tried so far:

```
Service worker on `static/service-worker.js`
Service worker on @GetMapping("/service-worker.js") @ResponseBody
```

In both cases i can read the file from brower in /service-worker.js but the registration fails with the same exception.

EDIT: (This is the registration I had problems with)

```
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log("Will the service worker register?");
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(function(reg){
            console.log("Yes, it did.");
        }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("No it didn't. This happened: ", err)
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My script trying to register was in `/store/All`. Registering with `navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')` was calling `/store/service-worker.js` which was being redirected according to a rule I had programmed in my controller.

The right call should be: `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')`  This ensures we call the service-worker.js in root and not in the same path as the current page.

tl;dr I was missing a `/`